# Regular Expression vs KMP

Tags: string, pattern-matching

Hi can any one tell me why there we are not using Knuth Morris Pratt algorithms in modern programming practices and prefer regular expression more ?

Answer (score 2):

Is there more than one KMP algorithm?  My understanding is that there is one algorithm for performing a search for a string within another string.  Regex is much more flexible - and there's no reason why a very simple regex expression couldn't use KMP - it's up to the implementor.

Comment: The other algorithm is boyer-Moore, its borrows some KMP i guess.

The following link says, the way we compute next shift during mis-match is somewhat similar to finite automaton. Having said that, I'm assuming our Regex has some KMP in it. 

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html

Comment: Whichever way, ram, regex works and it works well - don't fix what ain't broken!  :)